# Simple way to expose an SQL database to R analysis through a web interface?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, r, web-applications

We have a Ruby on Rails app with a database that we're planning to add an R query interface to. It would be good to test this concept with a quick mockup though: some kind of canned R interface attached to the database. (Think PhyMyAdmin but running R queries.)

There are many [R web interfaces](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces), so I'm looking for some guidance here.

Requirements:

- easy to query the database
- can do graphs
- easy to install on CentOS
- ability to secure with username/password would be a bonus.
- integration with Ruby/Rails (eg, ability to use Ruby models rather than the tables directly) a big bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the packages in that list of R web interfaces are obselete or no longer maintained. Best options there are probably Rook and RApache. Not mentioned is [Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/), a new project from RStudio.

There are R packages to do everything on your list: for example [RMySQL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html) to connect and query a MySQL database. For graphs you have the choice of base graphics, [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html) or [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/). A quick web search suggests that something called EPEL is an option to install on CentOS using yum.

Integration with Ruby/Rails: possible, using e.g. [RSRuby](https://github.com/alexgutteridge/rsruby) (old) or perhaps a [Ruby client](https://github.com/clbustos/Rserve-Ruby-client) for Rserve, but not really recommended. Probably better to keep R and Rails code separate.

There'll be some coding involved; you won't find a "canned interface", but Shiny is probably the closest to that.

Comment: I've done some playing around: RServe and its client were trivial to get going. Rook/rApache looks a lot messier - no easy walkthroughs either. Lots of reading, configuration, etc.

Comment: And yeah, there are packages to do things - still a lot of glue code to write. Shiny looks good - very developer friendly.